# use Onclick to run a function to access object properties in js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a script that generates a paragraph of random text that works. It randomly selects words from an array and creates sentences that are joined into a paragraph.

Now I want to be able to choose from different arrays with different word tones to form the paragraphs via a list in an html file.

I made an object with the different word tones as separate properties, and their values being the different arrays. I tested this by passing the object.property into the paragraph function and that worked. So I know I can use an object.property to pass into the function.

Now, I have a number of list elements that I want to be able to use, each to choose a different word tone to populate the paragraph. I thought to use an onclick to call a function on the list with an if statement. And this should choose which property in the object to pass into the paragraph function.

The ipsumText that is returned should equal either of the two arrays.
This is not working though. 
Should this work? Can anyone advise where I have made a mistake in the code. I can’t work it out.

```
<li onclick="flavourChoice(xx)”>choice one</li>
<li onclick="flavourChoice(yy)”>choice two</li>


<script>

var ipsumTextxx = [words here...]
var ipsumTextyy = [different words here...]

var ipsumTextFlavour = {
    xx: ipsumTextxx,
    yy: ipsumTextyy
}

function flavourChoice(choice) {
    if(choice === xx) {
        ipsumText = ipsumTextFlavour.xx;   
    } else {
        ipsumText = ipsumTextFlavour.yy;
    }

    return(ipsumText)
}

/* then use ipsumText to pass into the various functions that create the paragraphs */

</script>
```

Comment: That hasn't worked. Am I using return in the correct way? Is this going to make the result available outside the function?

Comment: `flavourChoice(xx)` what is  `xx`?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I thought this is how I would differentiate between which link was selected in the list. So if I have three links in the html, xx, yy, zz and each corresponds to a different array for words to use.

Comment: is `xx` an object? where does it get declared?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov no. The list in the html is a list of words to click. If I click  "choice one" or "choice two" I need to be able to change the array that is used in the function. So I thought I need some value to pass in for the () when I call onclick = "flavourChoice()" , so the if statement can run.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li onclick="flavourChoice(xx)”>choice one</li>
```

you see the character **”** ? It should be **"**.

```
<li onclick="flavourChoice(xx)">choice one</li>
```

if `xx` is not an object, you should make it string:

```
<li onclick="flavourChoice('xx')">choice one</li>
```

Make it string in your function as well, then call your `generateParagraph()` function with `ipsumText`.

```
function flavourChoice(choice) {
    var ipsumText = {};

    if(choice === 'xx') {
        ipsumText = ipsumTextFlavour.xx;   
    } else {
        ipsumText = ipsumTextFlavour.yy;
    }
    generateParagraphs(ipsumText);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I think that stray " was something in the post. The code has the correct character. This is still not working for me. I was returning "ipsumText" because I thought I needed to make that result available outside the function flavourChoice

Comment: sorry, what I'm expecting is that the paragraph that is generated when I click the link, is using the words in the array "ipsumTextxx" if I click the link that has 'xx' as the string. But nothing happens. The paragraph doesn't generate at all.

Comment: You should call your `generateParagraph()` function

Comment: The original code called the generateParagraph() function, and that worked fine, but that was when I had no other options for the arrays to use. I thought needed some kind of function to tell the script which array to use to pass into the  generateParagraph() function. Shall I post a fiddle to see the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the linst of links in the html to

```
<li onclick="flavourChoice('xx')">choice one</li>
```

After some more research I found I could access the object properties more simply in the flavourChoice() function.

```
function flavourChoice(choice) {
    var ipsumText = ipsumTextFlavour[choice]; 
    console.log(ipsumText);
```

Following this in the original code were several functions leading to one final function that passed in the ipsumText value and changed the DOM element in the HTML.

I also added all of this inside the function above. Then I called the function that updates the DOM and this works. I can click a list of links, each one changes the array that is used to generate the paragraph.